# How to split fixed position file based on conditions in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, split, conditional-statements

I need to split file like if in line position 11 to 13 contains 003 then the whole line should go in a.txt rest all records should go in b.txt in unix
Tried csplit but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using awk

Try:

```
awk '{if (substr($0, 11, 3)=="003")print>"a.txt"; else print>"b.txt"}' file
```

#### Example

Consider, for example, this input file:

```
$ cat file
1234567890003keep
other line
```

We run our command:

```
$ awk '{if (substr($0, 11, 3)=="003")print>"a.txt"; else print>"b.txt"}' file
```

When the command finishes, there will two files in the current directory:

```
$ cat a.txt
1234567890003keep
```

And:

```
$ cat b.txt
other line
```

#### How it works

```
if (substr($0, 11, 3)=="003")print>"a.txt"; else print>"b.txt"
```

The condition, `substr($0, 11, 3)=="003"`, checks to see if, on the current line, the three characters starting at position 11 are `003`.  If they are then the current line is printed to `a.txt`:

```
print>"a.txt"
```

If they aren't, then the line is printed to `b.txt`:

```
print>"b.txt"
```

## Using grep

```
grep '^..........003' file >a.txt
grep -v '^..........003' file >b.txt
```

## Using sed

```
sed -e '/^..........003/{w a.txt' -e 'd}' file >b.txt
```

Comment: Thanks John it is working nicely. Is there any other way without AWK? As my filesystem gets hung with excess use of AWK as this will be used for around 30 GB files and 8 files at a time.

Comment: @KumarParera I just added two other methods.  What OS are you on?  It is very unlikely that it is  awk that causes your system to hang unless you are using Sun/Solaris.